# Convert an Byte string or string to an integer in Python

Tags: python, string, byte

I have both a string and Bytes types in my Python program and I am looking to convert it to a number or the corresponding Ascii character.
the  has a value of 11000000 and
the  has a value b'11000000' 
I have tried using the struct to convert the bytes type but I received an error saying it required a length of one. However, it is 1 byte long.

I have looked at other questions but none seem to work. It's the value of the byte I'm looking for.
Can anyone suggest the best way to convert one of these to an integer or a char?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `int(a, 2)`?

Comment: I would recommend the advanced method `sum(j<<i for i,j in enumerate(map(int,b_str)[::-1]))`

Answer (score 0):

Just convert to an integer with base 2 argument:

```
print chr(int(b'11000000', 2)) # the À character
```